# DirectX clear backbuffer issues

Tags: windows-store-apps, directx-11

I'm a beginner to DirectX, so the solution may seem obvious to you. I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=111-4-4) teaching me how to set up a simple directx project with no starting code, and so far the tutorials are working perfectly. The problem is now that I have it clearing the backbuffer in my Render() function, it will not set the background to any color but black.

Here's my Render() function:

```
//set render target
devcon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, rendertarget.GetAddressOf(), nullptr);

//clear backbuffer to blue
float color[4] = { 0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f };
devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(rendertarget.Get(), color);

//TODO: Render code here

//swap buffers
swapchain->Present(1, 0);
```

and my setup in the initialization:

```
//get a ptr to the backBuffer
ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> backbuffer;
swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), &backbuffer);

//create a render target pointing to the backBuffer
dev->CreateRenderTargetView(backbuffer.Get(), nullptr, &rendertarget);
```

Comment: I don't see any error handling in your code.  Are you certain that all your method calls are succeeding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for clearing the back buffer to blue is correct.

There must be a type or failure somewhere else.

Comment: It turns out I was using DX11.1 functions in a DX11.2 project. Re-creating the project in VS2012 instead of 2013 fixed this. Thanks!

Comment: Nice catch. 2013 take's a little setup to get regular 11 working.